# How can I make taskbar and title bar un-transparent when maximize a window in Windows 7?

Tags: windows-7, desktop, aero, transparency

This way, I can be more concentrated on the window, not be disturbed by those transparency stuff in taskbar and title bar.

Yes I know I can disable window transparency but this is not what I want.
In Windows Vista, system will automatically disable transparency when a window is maximized, and when no window is maximized, transparency will automatically come back.
I like it this way, and wish to know if there is a way to make Windows 7 works like this.

Thanks.

Comment: When Vista came out many people were asking how to make window borders and the taskbar transparent, like how it is in Windows 7.

Comment: Create your own theme with http://vistastylebuilder.com/download.html which does what you want.

Comment: Thank you paradroid, I know the fact about this, but I don't think it's right. And I also don't think cut entire aero glass off in the new Windows is right, too. And thank you magicandre1981, I'll give it a try.